# Is there a way to expose a CiviReport on a Wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress, civireport

Reports are not one of the component options available when using a shortcode in wordpress. What is the recommended way to expose a civireport on a wordpress page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run your report and copy all the info after wp-admin/admin.php and paste that after your page URL it will drop the report in. The data you from the report url begins with a "?" and looks similar to this.

```
?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Freport%2Finstance%2F50&reset=1&force=1
```

So you URL to show the report on the WordPress page will look like this.

```
https://<<site URL>>/<<page slug>>/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Freport%2Finstance%2F50&reset=1&force=1
```

Keep in mind you may need to adjust permissions depending on what user roles should be able to view this page.

Hope this helps.